# Invalid Argument error : foreach

Tags: php, foreach, arguments

I am getting an error messge as **invalid argument supplied for foreach()** when running the following code:

```
$datatoconvert = "Some Word";
$converteddata = "";
$n=1;

$converteddata .=$datatoconvert[0];

foreach ($datatoconvert as $arr) {
 if($arr[n] != ' ') {
  $n++;
 } else {
  $n++;
  $converteddata .=$arr[n];
 }
}
```

The code should find first character of every word and return a string with these characters. So in the above example I am trying to get output as "SW".

Answer (score 1):

You need to explode the string $datatoconvert into an array first.

```
$words = explode(' ', $datatoconvert);
```

should do the trick. Then foreach() on $words.

Answer (score 1):

You must provide an array or an iterable for the `foreach`.

To achieve what you are trying to do:

```
$string = "Some Word";
$string = trim($string); //Removes extra white-spaces aroud the $string

$pieces = explode(" ", $string); //Splits the $string at the white-spaces

$output = "";  //Creates an empty output string
foreach ($pieces as $piece) {
   if ($piece) //Checks if the piece is not empty
     $output .= substr($piece, 0, 1); //Add the first letter to the output
}
```

Remember, if you are using multibyte string, read about PHP mbstring functions.

Hope I have helped.

Answer (score 1):

when you do

```
$datatoconvert = "Some Word";
$converteddata = "";
$n=1;

$converteddata .=$datatoconvert[0];
```

what you will get is([**Live output**](http://codepad.org/C0Xqgndz))

```
string(1) "S"
```

you can get easily by explode instead

```
$datatoconvert = "Some Word";
$converteddata = "";

$words = explode(" ", $datatoconvert );
foreach ($words as $a) {
  $converteddata .= $a[0];
}
echo $converteddata ;
```

[**Live output**](http://codepad.org/AeJOomtC)